# Not able to subscribe to a topic in dapr using grpc with python

Tags: python, grpc, publish-subscribe

I am having a difficult time finding gRPC pub-sub subscriber template for python.

What I am trying is this, but it doesn't seem to work out.

```
class DaprClientServicer(daprclient_services.DaprClientServicer):
    def OnTopicEvent(self, request, context):
        if request.topic=="TOPIC_A":
            print("Do something")
            response = "some response"
        return response

server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
daprclient_services.add_DaprClientServicer_to_server(DaprClientServicer(), server)
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
server.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(86400)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```

My publish statement looks something like this:

```
client.PublishEvent(dapr_messages.PublishEventEnvelope(topic='TOPIC_A', data=data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Old Answer (Dapr's Python-SDK APIs changed significantly after this)

After doing a bit of research I found that I was skipping on the step.
So how subscriber work is like this:

1. Subscribe to a topic. (missing step)
2. Handel the messaged published to the subscribed topic.

Doing this worked for me:

```
# Our server methods
class DaprClientServicer(daprclient_services.DaprClientServicer):
    def GetTopicSubscriptions(self, request, context):
        # Dapr will call this method to get the list of topics the app
        # wants to subscribe to. In this example, we are telling Dapr
        # To subscribe to a topic named TOPIC_A
        return daprclient_messages.GetTopicSubscriptionsEnvelope(topics=['TOPIC_A'])

    def OnTopicEvent(self, request, context):
        logging.info("Event received!!")
        return empty_pb2.Empty()


# Create a gRPC server
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
daprclient_services.add_DaprClientServicer_to_server(
    DaprClientServicer(), server)

# Start the gRPC server
print('Starting server. Listening on port 50051.')
server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
server.start()

# Since server.start() doesn't block, we need to do a sleep loop
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(86400)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    server.stop(0)
```